# Vba intersection of heading row and column of target cell to get the heading of column

Tags: vba, excel, intersect

I am trying to get the column of the active cell and then find its intersection with the named range.

```
Sheet1.cells(3,5).value = Sheet2.cells(Intersect(Range("rngHeadingRowofSheet"), Target.Column)).Value
```

Target is the active cell whose column it will take and find the value of intersected cell with heading row named range.

But am getting type mismatch error. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sheet1.Cells(3,5).Value = Intersect(Sheet2.Range("rngHeadingRowofSheet"), Target.EntireColumn).Value
```

Comment: I tried this.The active cell is in some other sheet and the the value fetched is being stored in other sheet, so that is why am doing sheet2.cells(intersect code).value.

Comment: It gives invalid procedure call or  argument

Comment: In which Code module and which procedure do you have this code?
Please try the now edited code

Comment: No problem, im glad to be of service!